# How to read values from Custom txt file in Java

Tags: java, file

I want to read the values from custom text file in Java.

Here is my text file shown below:

```
Classroom1
Student1 Name, Student1 Surname , Student1 Age
Student2 Name, Student2 Surname , Student2 Age
Student3 Name, Student3 Surname , Student3 Age
Student4 Name, Student4 Surname , Student4 Age
...
Classroom2
Student1 Name, Student1 Surname , Student1 Age
Student2 Name, Student2 Surname , Student2 Age
Student3 Name, Student3 Surname , Student3 Age
Student4 Name, Student4 Surname , Student4 Age
...
Classroom3
...
```

I tried to implement some coding stuff but I couldn't handle with the process.

I want to add all students to each classroom. I thought to use `Map<String,List<Student>>` to handle with that but I couldn't implement the process of reading the values.

How can I do that?

Here is the code snippet shown below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); // detect inputs from the terminal input, System.in
    List<Student> students;
    while(in.hasNextLine()) { // while the scanner has a next line
      in.nextLine();
      String[] s = in.nextLine().split(",");
      students.add(new Student(s[0], s[1], s[2]));
    }
  }
  public class Student {
    public String name;
    public String surname;
    public int age;
    public Student(String name, String surname, int age) {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem and where in the code are you reading from a specific file?

Comment: For starters `List<Student> students;` is not enough. You need to initialize that variable, like `List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran I cannot add the all students from each classroom. I thought to use Map like `Map<String,List<Student>>`. Bu I couldn't do that.

Comment: First of all, you are trying to read from System.in not the text file, secondly you have to parse s[2] to an integer, Integer.parseInt(s[2]), try do add more information in the future, like error message, etc.

Comment: also remove this line: in.nextLine(); as you read two lines in one loop pass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote in your question:

> I want to add all students to each classroom. I thought to use Map<String,List>

I assume that the `Map` key is the name of the classroom, for example *Classroom1* that appears on a line, by itself, in the sample file (named *students.txt*) in your question. And the `Map` value is the `List` of students in that classroom.

Consider the following:
(Notes after the code.)

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Student {
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private int age;

    public Student(String name, String surname, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path source = Paths.get("students.txt");
        try (Scanner s = new Scanner(source)) {
            Map<String, List<Student>> classrooms = new HashMap<>();
            String classroom = "";
            while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = s.nextLine();
                if (line.startsWith("Classroom")) {
                    classroom = line;
                    classrooms.put(classroom, new ArrayList<Student>());
                }
                String[] fields = line.split(",");
                if (fields.length == 3) {
                    try {
                        int age = Integer.parseInt(fields[2].trim());
                        Student stud = new Student(fields[0].trim(), fields[1].trim(), age);
                        List<Student> students = classrooms.get(classroom);
                        students.add(stud);
                    }
                    catch (NumberFormatException xNumberFormat) {
                        // Ignore
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            xIo.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

- You don't need a separate class with just a `main` method, in order to run your program. Class `Student` can also contain a `main` method.
- The code in your question tries to get values from the user rather than reading the *students.txt* file.
- According to the sample data in your question, there are spaces around the commas on some of the lines in the *students.txt* file. Hence the calls to method [trim](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#trim()).
- The above code uses [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).
- You need to convert the last field of the lines containing student details from a `String` to an `int`. Hence the call to method `parseInt`. That method may throw `NumberFormatException` and therefore the call is inside a *try-catch*. If the `String` cannot be converted to an `int`, then I simply ignore that line. You may wish to do something else. I couldn't ascertain from your question how you want to handle invalid lines in the *student.txt* file, i.e. lines that don't contain the expected data.
- Method `get`, of interface `java.util.Map`, may return null. The above code does not handle that situation because it should not occur. You may need to modify the above code such that it does handle the situation where method `get` returns null.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that answer is exactly what you want look for, but i've done my best to guess what you may want to do :)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static final String FILE_PATH = "src/students.txt";
    public static final String STUDENT_FIELDS_SEPARATOR = ",";
    public static final String CLASSROOM_SEPARATOR = "...";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, List<Student>> classroomMap = parseStudentsFile();
        System.out.println(classroomMap);
    }

    private static Map<String, List<Student>> parseStudentsFile() {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILE_PATH))) {
            AtomicReference<String> currClassroom = new AtomicReference<>("");
            return reader.lines().map(line -> {
                String[] splitLine = line.split(STUDENT_FIELDS_SEPARATOR);
                if (splitLine.length == 1 && !splitLine[0].equals(CLASSROOM_SEPARATOR)) {
                    currClassroom.set(splitLine[0]);
                } else if (splitLine.length == 3) {
                    try {
                        return Map.entry(currClassroom, new Student(splitLine[0].strip(), splitLine[1].strip(), Integer.parseInt(splitLine[2].strip())));
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        System.out.println("NumberFormatException - line ignored, cannot parse: " + line);
                        return null;
                    }
                } else return null;
                return null;
            })
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                            o -> o.getKey().toString(),
                            Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
public class Student {
    private final String name;
    private final String surname;
    private final int age;

    public Student(String name, String surname, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", surname='" + surname + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }
}
```

students.txt

```
Classroom1
Student1 Name, Student1 Surname , 1
Student2 Name, Student2 Surname , 2
Student3 Name, Student3 Surname , 3
Student4 Name, Student4 Surname , 4
...
Classroom2
Student1 Name, Student1 Surname , 1
Student2 Name, Student2 Surname , 2
Student3 Name, Student3 Surname , 3
Student4 Name, Student4 Surname , 4
...
```

output

```
{Classroom2=[Student{name='Student1 Name', surname='Student1 Surname', age=1}, Student{name='Student2 Name', surname='Student2 Surname', age=2}, Student{name='Student3 Name', surname='Student3 Surname', age=3}, Student{name='Student4 Name', surname='Student4 Surname', age=4}], Classroom1=[Student{name='Student1 Name', surname='Student1 Surname', age=1}, Student{name='Student2 Name', surname='Student2 Surname', age=2}, Student{name='Student3 Name', surname='Student3 Surname', age=3}, Student{name='Student4 Name', surname='Student4 Surname', age=4}]}
```

Comment: I revised my post.

Comment: I've also updated my answer according to additional requirements you provided

Answer (score 0):

Usually you do want to read this sort of data from a specific type of file, like .xml or something like that.
In your case, you have to find a way to get rid of all the spaces and additional characters and extract from each line [Name, Surname, Age].
Here is the solution:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(file); 
        ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
        while (in.hasNextLine()) { // while the scanner has a next line
            String[] s = in.nextLine().split(",");
            if (!s[0].equals("...") && !s[0].contains("Classroom")) {
                String[] age = s[2].split(" ");
                String[] name = s[0].split(" ");
                String[] surname = s[1].split(" ");
                students.add(new Student(name[1], surname[2],Integer.parseInt(age[2])));
            
            }
        }
        for (Student student : students) {
            System.out.println(student.toString());

        }
    }

    public static class Student {
        public String name;
        public String surname;
        public int age;

        public Student(String name, String surname, int age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.surname = surname;
            this.age = age;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
           return "Student{" +
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    ", surname='" + surname + '\'' +
                    ", age=" + age +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```